# Security issue using Rails, CKEditor, and Roxy fileman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, roxy-fileman

I've been using Ckeditor in my Rails app for a while now, but recently I needed to add the capability to upload html5 videos as well.  I added a plugin to CKEditor to utilize the html5 'video' tag, but the generic 'browse server' functionality in CKEditor won't let me upload an mp4 (it just shows the filename as a # sign.)

my solution was to add the Roxy fileman to handle the uploads, and it work great, except there's no security at all in it by default (if the fileman is in a public folder, which is the only way i can see to do it in Rails.)

The only thing Roxy offers is a checkAccess script that gets run before each PHP script gets run, but there's no way for that script to know if the user is logged in or not.

I was thinking I could use x-sendfile to have rails check the permissions, but that seems like using a sledgehammer to hang a picture frame (and it might not even be the right way to do things here.)  To me, there should be a simple answer.

Any ideas?